# Accessing My Computer from Android mobile

Tags: windows-7, networking, android, remote-access

Is there any possibilities to access my computer from my android mobile without installing any third party software in my computer?.I need to access computer like remote desktop connection. If anyone knows kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this without installing a 3rd party app but you need a Chrome plug-in called Chrome Remote Desktop. You will also have to install Chrome Remote Desktop Android app on your cell phone.

Do a Google search for getting both. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.